# Implementing try-catch inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, user-input

I want to create a try-catch block inside a loop to give the user multiple opportunities to enter the info with the correct format. When I enter something with incorrect format, the program displays the sysout message "Please enter name and age with correct format." from the catch block.

The problem is when I enter the info with the correct formatting after this message, it keeps displaying the same message "Please enter name and age with correct format." even though it should exit and ask if I want to continue.

Here's what I have:

```
        int inAge;
        String inName;

        while (true) {
            try {
                inAge = Integer.parseInt((input.substring((input.indexOf(',') + 1))));
                inName = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(','));
                list.add(new Plant(inName, inAge));
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter name and age with correct format.");
                in.next();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Yes or No)");
        endOrNo = in.nextLine();

        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(endOrNo))
            go = true;
        else
            go = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

possible that you call next() instead of nextLine(), that may read wrong input and keep taking you back to the exception block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value of input variable as so.

```java
while (true) {
            try {
                input = in.nextLine(); // accept input
                inAge = Integer.parseInt((input.substring((input.indexOf(',') + 1))));
                inName = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(','));
                list.add(new Plant(inName, inAge));
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter name and age with correct format.");
                input = in.next();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Yes or No)");
        endOrNo = in.nextLine();

        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(endOrNo))
            go = true;
        else
            go = false;
```